# Automapper from flat model to multiple complex properties of the same type

Tags: c#, .net, automapper

Is there a way to get automapper to map the following without having to map each property or create different view models for each address?

Source:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public decimal? BillingAddressLatitude { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? BillingAddressLongitude { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string BillingAddressUnit { get; set; }
    public long? MailingAddressCityId { get; set; }
    public decimal? MailingAddressLatitude { get; set; }
    public string MailingAddressLine1 { get; set; }
    public string MailingAddressLine2 { get; set; }
    public string MailingAddressLine3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? MailingAddressLongitude { get; set; }
    public string MailingAddressPostalCode { get; set; }
    public string MailingAddressUnit { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Destinations:

```
public class Model
{
    public Address BillingAddress { get; set; }
    public Address MailingAddress { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public decimal? Latitude { get; set; }
    public string Line1 { get; set; }
    public string Line2 { get; set; }
    public string Line3 { get; set; }
    public decimal? Longitude { get; set; }
    public string PostalCode { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; } 
}
```

This have been my map attempt.

```
CreateMap<ViewModel, Address>();
CreateMap<ViewModel, Model>()
    .ForMember(d => d.BillingAddress, o => o.MapFrom(s => s))
    .ForMember(d => d.MailingAddress, o => o.MapFrom(s => s));
```

This gets me both addresses initialized but the properties are always null.

If there is no auto filling of this properties in any configuration, I will accept defeat and will map each property individually.

Thank you for your input.

Comment: Looks like you'll have to map each property individually unfortunately. Automapper supports auto-assignment by property name, but sadly the property names don't match up. See :[Auto Mapper docs](https://automapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Getting-started.html)

Comment: http://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Reverse-Mapping-and-Unflattening.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

Mappings

```
public class ReverseMappingProfile : Profile
{
    public ReverseMappingProfile()
    {
        RecognizeDestinationPrefixes("Billing", "Mailing");

        CreateMap<Model, ViewModel>()
            .ReverseMap();
        CreateMap<Address, ViewModel>()
            .ReverseMap();
    }
}
```

Config

```
var mappingConfig = new MapperConfiguration(mc =>
{
   mc.AddProfile(new ReverseMappingProfile());
});

IMapper mapper = mappingConfig.CreateMapper();
```

Execution

```
var model = new Model
{
    Name = "Joe Bloggs",
    BillingAddress = new Address
    {
        Line1 = "Line 1",
        Line2 = "Line 1",
        Line3 = "Line 1",
        PostalCode = "ABCDEF",
        Latitude = 1232,
        Longitude = 4321,
        Unit = "A Unit"
    },
    MailingAddress = new Address
    {
        Line1 = "M Line 1",
        Line2 = "M Line 1",
        Line3 = "M Line 1",
        PostalCode = "MMFDS",
        Latitude = 6543,
        Longitude = 78990,
        Unit = "M Unit"
    },
};

var viewModel = mapper.Map<ViewModel>(model);

var newModel = mapper.Map<Model>(viewModel);
```